# Auto deployment in cpanel repository with git error

Tags: git, continuous-deployment, cpanel-uapi

I need your help with the next issue: Following cpanel documentation I've created a git version repository on my remote server and i've created cpanel.yml file in the root repository to automathic deploy any push in the public directory as indicated in documentation, but when I push to the repository I'm getting this error:

```
func: create
module: VersionControlDeployment
result: 
  data: ~
  errors: 
    - You do not have the feature “version_control”.
  messages: ~
  metadata: {}

  warnings: ~
```

It seems not finding this instruction *VersionControlDeployment* but manual deployment is possible. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a problem with your ssh keys.
Try the following:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 2048 -C serverusername@serverdomain.com
```